# How can I get the date of the last day of current fiscal year in a formula?

Tags: force.com, formula

I need to calculate the days between today and the end of the fiscal year. I found some examples in Apex using Period sObject but was wondering if there's a way of getting this in a formula, since it would be more elegant to use a formula field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible.

SF help docs suggest pretty much hardcoding your "boundary dates" in formulas if formula is what you need: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005630. Pretty ridiculous really because it means in couple of years you'll forget about it (or won't work there anymore) and suddenly it'll "break". Also - formulas have limited size...

There are no FISCAL-related functions in [function reference](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?language=en&id=customize_functions.htm). And [usage of custom fiscal year means you're losing the SOQL equivalents too](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_about_cfy.htm&language=en_US#forecast_impacts), never to see them again.

> When custom fiscal years are enabled, you can't use the
>   FISCAL_MONTH(), FISCAL_QUARTER(), or FISCAL_YEAR() date functions in
>   SOQL.

Upvote https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqRcAAK but I'd say for most flexible solution you have to resort to Apex...

Comment: Yeap, that was my conclusion before posting the answer. Was hoping I was missing something. I'm already working on using a trigger. For this case, the data is update dependent (not time dependent), so it will work. But I can imagine situations where a formula would be hard to replace...

Answer (score 0):

Date(YEAR(today()), Month, Day) -  TODAY()

fiscal years usually don't change, so you can get away with this

Comment: Some companies work in crazy mode: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%934%E2%80%935_calendar Idea is nice (month has always either 4 or 5 weeks and all months start on Monday for example) but at my current company it means May starts on May 5th. And last day of 2013 is Dec 28th.

Comment: Problem here is that I'm working on functionality that will be used in different companies and may use different fiscal years. We would need to setup the formula for each one, which makes the Trigger option more convenient.